# HTML doctype defined in html renders the font smaller

Tags: html

When I included the Doctype entry in my HTML, the fonts are getting displayed smaller in size and alignment distorted. I included the doctype to avoid some of the css styles not appearing properly.

Doctype which i used is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Pls provide me a suggestion to avoid the font size change and alignment.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `doctype` string that triggers “standards mode”, as the one mentioned in the question does, you get *all* of the “standards mode” features that a browser has (they vary by browser). This typically includes handling font sizes by CSS specifications, instead of simulating bugs of older browser by [quirks mode](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) features.

Thus, the solution is to use HTML and CSS by the specs. For more detailed advice, the specific problem should be identified in a reproduceable manner. Possible issues: In quirks mode, font size keywords like `medium` may be interpreted incorrectly; font size setting as percentage for a table cell may be misinterpreted as relating to browser’s default font size (instead of parent element’s font size); and font properties might not be inherited from `body` or other enclosing elements into tables. So probably your page now relies on some of these bugs.

Comment: To add, modern web pages require a strict doctype and no new web pages should be using transitional doctypes since they were only created to help developers 'transition' from old, deprecated markup back in 1999.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put px after the font size:

font-size:24px;

I had the same issue and it worked for me.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm guessing it is because of the doctype being strict. So the details are expected.

Answer (score 0):

The longer doctype is preferred because it puts browsers in Standards Mode (AKA Strict Mode), while the short version or no doctype at all gives you Quirks Mode. And that's the cause for the size difference.

So basically have you tried the HTML5 doctype?

```
<!doctype html>
```

Maybe it will make a difference

Try read the above links. Maybe you will find something useful.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/the-doctype-tag-and-its-effect-on-page-rendering.html

https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/

Comment: The HTML5 doctype triggers standards mode as well... making it no different from the "longer" doctypes.

Comment: can i have 2 different doctype defined in 2 different jsp files which are inserted in a single parent jsp? like "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">" in first jsp and this "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">" in second jsp?